# Firebird.Select columns from table.Some column may not exists

Tags: firebird2.5

I have similar query:

```
select 
a, 
b, 
c, 
d, 
e,
(select somevalue from differenttable where report.a = two.a) as two,
(select somevalue from differenttable2 where report.a = three.a) as three,
(select sum(kol*CAST(price AS BIGINT)) from "otherreport"('01.01.2010', '01.10.2010') as sum
from "report"('01.01.2010', '01.10.2010')
```

The query works in its original form, but the problem is that in some of the databases(old versions) that i query some of the fields a, b, c, d, e are missing in the result of 'report' stored procedure and i get an error.What would be the best way to handle this ?
I was thinking of select * from reports, but i can not add the subqueries. May be i can not find the right syntaxis to do this.Other way would be to check if the columns exists before
making the select...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you can do:

- Use an aliased `SELECT *` followed by the subqueries. Instead of doing a simple `SELECT *` you alias the selectable stored procedure and use `myAlias.*`:

  ```
  SELECT 
    r.*,
    (select somevalue from differenttable where report.a = two.a) as two,
    ...
  from "report"('01.01.2010', '01.10.2010') r
  ```

  Note that this has its own downsides, like moving the "missing columns" problem from the query to the consumer of the query.
- Upgrade your databases so that the stored procedure matches your expectations.
- Dynamically build the query from the procedure metadata. This is pretty complex, and I currently don't have time to give a full example of this.

Comment: Aliased select was all i needed.Thank you.Second option is not accepted because databases are not in my control.Third option is too complex.Moving problem to consumer is all i wanted.I know which columns could be missing and i wont't use it in case they are missing.Thank you again.